# Not able to start appserver due to the missing batch file

Tags: weblogic

I have installed weblogic 12.2.3.1.0 and when I tried to start the appserver its failing because not able to find common\bin\startpointbase.cmd batch file. 
But it didn't come with installation. can any of you let me know where can I find that file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

This script starts a PointBase database that you could use for your domain, it's inside weblogic_home/common/bin/.

It is shipped with weblogic, you need to run startpointbase.cmd  before starting your weblogic instance if you are using it.

Before starting it make sure all path variable are set.

Comment: PointBase is no longer provided with WebLogic Server 12c, now it's Apache Derby.

Comment: If you have upgraded your domain from an earlier version of WebLogic you have to replace PointBase with another database. Apache Derby (like pointbase) should only be used for development purpose.

Comment: Actually I have installed  oracle customercare and billing application appserver as weblogic. Its like upgrading my previous application . when I start the server with command start.cmd weblogic server window is opening and shutting down immediately. what might be the reason ? anybody guess. Logs don't have much information .one of the log contains like its failing because not able to find startpointbase.cmd